# How to render components dynamically and apply dynamic CSS in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have created Directive but how to add css styling in it.
Also, tried with array object but had applied css in html but I want to create single component where I want to pass attributes like width, height, border, text to render components dynamically and if want to create more components then have to update only in single component file.

Answer (score 0):

To add **styles dinamically** can be a tricky thing in angular. One can not add any variable to the `stiles = ""` tag, instead you have to use something like

```
<div [style.background]="variableWithColor"> </div>
```

or

```
<div [style.color]="variableWithColor"> </div>
```

info about this here: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#style-binding

If you want to do this from a **directive created by you**, then you will need something like this: Import and inject `ElementRef` (from @angular/core) in your directive:

```
constructor(public el: ElementRef) {}
```

Then you can use it in this way (for instance with background color):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
```

Comment: @GMARKAN , did you try it?, Did you find difficulties ?

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, could you please mark it as accepted?, That would be very much appreciated ;) .